# Thunderbird portable Searches multiple mail boxes

Tags: windows-xp, thunderbird, search, portable, local

I have a portable installation of Thunderbird 3 (WinXP) with my old archive with four local mail boxes. I would like to search in all mail boxes at same time, but I can't do it. I havealready enabled "enable index search". I don't know if system is working in underground, but it seems does not do it.

Do you know if I need a "installable" Thunderbird rather than portable? Or do you have any tricks to activate searches in all mail boxes? I need it as my archive and I will never need to reply or something else. Maybe I need to export to another system? Google desktop?

Your recommendations will be very appreciated